# oracle to postgresql connectivity

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g

I'm using `postgresql 9.1` and `oracle 11gR2` 64 bit windows.
I'm trying Heterogeneous DB Connection Between Oracle 11gR2 And Postgresql 9.1.
here the info:

I configured by reading these links
http://dbaspot.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/how-to-access-postgresql-from-oracle-database/
http://manojadinesh.blogspot.in/2012/05/heterogeneous-db-connection-between.html

When I tried this command

```
select * from "testtable"@PG_LINK;
```

I got an error like

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```